# NotePad++ - How to remove or replace newline characters?

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace, newlines

Within my notepad++ environment, I have the following value on a page...

```
test me out
</li>
```

I can search and find the ending `</li>` value with....

```
\n</li>
```

but what do I need to replace that value with in order to get this result...

```
test me out</li>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Windows a [linebreak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) consists of two characters: carriage return and line feed, so you have to search for `\r\n</li>` and replace with just `</li>`.

Comment: To add to MBu, make sure that the **Search Mode** in Find dialogue is set to **Extended (\n, \r...)**